# SQL Server connection to local MS Access 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have created a relational database in MS Access 2010. Till now it is local and one user access only. Now i need to make it multi-user friendly. So is it possible to connect local MS Access software to a remote SQL Server ? I am willing to use MS Access software not any web based application.

In summery, 
Multiple people from different location will use their MS Access Software to manipulate/sync the remote SQL Server database.

It will be good to receive any experts opinion or suggestion.

Thanks In advance
PKS

Comment: I work across MS Access and Amazon RDS at the moment, and it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Export your data from MS Access database into SQL Server, then use MS Access to link to the SQL Server database.

https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Import-or-link-to-SQL-Server-data-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e#bm2